# I cannot map certain fields (FormattedValues) from the OData service using the OData Client in the .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata, dataverse

I'm querying the Dataverse OData API server using the Microsoft.OData.Client.
I made a class which inherits DataServiceContext and I have property which represents Entity Set that I query.

That works perfectly, but I cannot map fields with name like field_name@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue.
For example:

```
        [OriginalName("field_name@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue")]        
        public string? FieldName{ get; set; }
```

In cases like this, I'm always getting the null values. There are regular values when I use the Postman.

Did anyone have same problem?

Comment: According to the documentation for the OriginalName attribute which says: "Denotes the original name of a variable defined in metadata.". The properties like this are not a part of the metadata, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: But you can get it through Postman, isn't it accessing data through OData when using Postman to call?

Comment: You cannot directly query this field using the OData annotation. You will get this property if you add "Prefer" http header and set the value to odata.include-annotations="OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue".